# Pricing guide for a necromantic item

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew, economy

Hello I'm looking for some help pricing an item that specifically only uses the [animate dead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead) option to maintain control of the animated dead once per day. I know there won't be a RAW solution but was wondering if there were some example items I could use to come up with pricing with my DM. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, This site is geared towards clarifying rules more than building character concepts or homebrew items. A couple great places to ask would be r/3d6 and r/DnDHomebrew

Comment: We’ve done well in the past with magic item homebrew reviews that asked “what rarity should this item be”? Exact price isn’t really something we can do, but we can put a rarity on the item.

Comment: This has no business being closed.

Comment: I was specifically looking for evidence toward what level of rarity to give it using already existing examples. Maybe my terminology is fuzzy? Are there any possible edits I can make it make it more acceptable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This should be priced as an uncommon item

While the game does a bad job in grouping items into commonality slots, which by the rules determine the price range, in general items tend to be more rare the more powerful they are.

A comparable item it a *pearl of power*, which allows you to regain up to a 3rd level spell slot once per day, and is an uncommon item that requires attunement.

As an uncommon item, it should be priced from 101 - 500 gp (DMG p. 135). The exact value is up to you.

Other uncommon items that provide multiple use of a spell like *eyes of charming* or *circlet of blasting* provide three uses, and this does not even provide a full spell, so I would likely put this at the lower end of the uncommon price range.

Because this is not a full spell, should it maybe be common?

There are no common reusable items in the core rules. Xanathar's Guide does introduce several, and prefaces them with this guidance:

> The Dungeon Master's Guide includes many magic items of every rarity. The one exception are common items; that book includes few of them. This section introduces more of them to the game. These items **seldom increase a character's power, but they are likely to amuse players** and provide fun roleplaying opportunities.

It lists items such as an armor that never gets dirty, or a cloack that you can make billow dramatically as a bonus action.

This item is not just for fun flavor, it does have a real mechanical effect, that will save the character using it the use of a daily spell slot, but the effect is weaker than a full use of the matching, 3rd level spell, so it should not be common.